# How to debug problems in Linux kernel module `init()`?

Tags: linux, remote-debugging, kernel-module, debug-symbols

I am using remote (k)gdb to debug a problem in a module that causes a panic when loaded e.g. when `init()` is called.

The stack trace just shows that `do_one_initcall(mod->init)` causes the crash. In order to get the symbol file loaded in the gdb, I need to get the address of the module text section, and to get that I need to get the module loaded.

Because the `insmod` in busybox (1.16.1) doesn't support `-m` so I'm stuck to `grep modulename /proc/modules` + adding the offset from `nm` to figure out the address.

So I'm facing a sort a of a chicken and an egg problem here - to be able to debug the module loading, I need to get the module loaded - but in order to get the module loaded, I need to debug the problem...

So I am currently thinking about two options - is there a way to get the address information either:

1. by printk() in the module init code
2. by printk() somewhere in the kernel code

all this prior to calling the `mod->init()` - so I could place a breakpoint there, load the symbol file, hit <kbd>c</kbd> and see it crash and burn...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you build your code into the kernel rather than as a module? That might simplify debugging the `init()` call.

You could also set a breakpoint at `do_one_initcall()` and look at the address of `mod->init` to get the load address.

Comment: Compiling the code into kernel would be way too cumbersome (the need to flash the board every time as opposed to wget to a ramdisk). breaking in `do_one_initcall()` helped enough to pinpoint the problem so that I could postpone the crash until starting an usermode process communicating with the module. Thanks.